# Thinning and renaming packages for ghci and scripting

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghci

For scripting and playing around in ghci I want to import `Data.Matrix` from the package `matrix`.
Base already contains `Data.Matrix` but from another package: `matrices`.

I've been able to work around this successfully with PackageImports:
For ghci I do:

```
$ stack exec --resolver lts-12.5 --package "matrix" -- ghci
Prelude> :set -XPackageImports
Prelude> import "matrix" Data.Matrix
```

and for scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --package matrix

{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}

import "matrix" Data.Matrix

main = putStrLn $ Data.Matrix.prettyMatrix 
                $ Data.Matrix.fromList 1 1 [1]
```

executed with `stack ghc script.hs; ./script.hs`

But the [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-PackageImports) says "You probably don’t need to use this ... See also 'Thinning and renaming modules' for an alternative way ..."

[There](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-thinning-and-renaming), it is suggested to use e.g. `-package "base (Data.Bool as Bool)"` so I wanted to try that and figured for my case it would be either something like

- `-package "base (Data.Matrix as Mx)"` to rename the existing which I want to ignore, or
- `-package "matrix (Data.Matrix as Mx)"` to add a custom name for the module that I want.

But I can't even make the example work:

```
stack exec -package "base (Data.Bool as Bool)" -- ghci
Invalid option `-package'

Did you mean this?
    --package
...

stack exec --package "base (Data.Bool as Bool)" -- ghci
The following errors occurred while parsing the build targets:
- Directory not found: (Data.Bool
- Directory not found: Bool)

stack exec -package base (Data.Bool as Bool) -- ghci
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

For scripting

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
(I've tried each of those separately)
-- stack  -package "base (Data.Bool as Bool)" 
-- stack  -package  base (Data.Bool as Bool)
-- stack --package "base (Data.Bool as Bool)"
-- stack --package  base (Data.Bool as Bool)

import Bool

main = putStrLn $ show True
```

doesn't compile (`stack ghc script2.hs`)

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( script2.hs, script2.o )

script2.hs:4:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Bool’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
4 | import Bool
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you find in [the GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/) concerns either options directly to *the GHC compiler*, or in the Haskell code itself. But you're using Stack for package management, which is an entirely different beast. (Sure enough it *invokes* GHC, but it does way more than that.)

When using Stack, there's no reason to dabble with PackageImports (unless you really need to import two modules together of the same name from different packages!). By default, Stack hides every package that isn't explicitly a dependency, so no need to rename anything; just use normal Stack options for specifying the packages, and simple imports in the actual Haskell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-12.5 runghc --package matrix

import Data.Matrix as M

main = putStrLn . prettyMatrix
                $ M.fromList 1 1 [1]
```

Make sure `stack` actually uses the resolver line, i.e. either

```
$ chmod +x matrixtest.hs
$ ./matrixtest
```

or

```
$ stack matrixtest.hs
```

but not `stack ghc matrixtest.hs` or something like that.

Comment: I just tried your code (`stack ghc script3.hs`) and I get `Ambiguous module name ‘Data.Matrix’:
      it was found in multiple packages: matrices-0.4.5 matrix-0.3.6.1`

Comment: Don't `stack ghc` it, that'll skip the resolver line in the file. Just execute the script itself.

Comment: This works! And `stack exec --resolver lts-12.5  --package matrix -- ghci` works for playing around. Thanks!